# how to Run spring Boot Application with out providing "spring.application.json"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have built a Spring Boot application with 2.1.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT using an initializer. While running in eclipse getting JSON parse exception.

When I use the `--spring.application.json={\"foo\":\"bar\"}` argument on the command line, it works. How can I make it work without having to type that every time?`

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.1.15.RELEASE
 

com.gktechtalks.blog
services
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
services
GKTechTalks Blog Services

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`

it is a brand new spring-boot project. Created from "https://start.spring.io/"
I imported the project into eclipse and ran Then I got below exception.
No configuration added from my side.

Got below exception

After then I have provided

```
--spring.application.json={\"foo\":\"bar\"}
```

Then Application starting without any exceptions. That is why I got a question why can't we run without that property in the command line.

Comment: can you add your code part that relies on the configuration value `spring.application.json`. A raw application created with the initializer should not rely on any config parameter and you should be able to run the application in Eclipse/IDEA or with `mvn spring-boot:run` directly

Comment: This looks like your programme code relies on these random data (which gets injected as JSON in the command line). The error (if this JSON is not there) might give you some information where this data is needed. If you supply the error message, we can try to help you more directly.

Comment: are you requesting at some point the property foo? like @Value("foo") ?

Comment: Use IntelliJ instead of Eclipse.  You won't have these problems.

Comment: @rieckpil I have added pom.xml and exception details.

Comment: @jpganz18 I don't have any code. Single spring-boot startup class.No coding started.downloaded from spring initializer and started running in eclipse.

Comment: @duffymo I have tried IntelliJ also.Same issue

Comment: @rieckpil  Maybe java version should be higher.I am using jdk1.8

Comment: do you have an empty application.properties ?